# Allow and Remove Elements Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I will receive an XML which has variable structure but will have 1 field for sure like

```
`
<Remove_Elements_List>isInJeopardy</Remove_Elements_List>
`
```

I should use the content of this Remove elements to identify a tag in the incoming xml and remove it using XSL I should also remove the Remove_Elements_List tag.

This should work regardless of namespace and element depth.

I wrote xslt like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="Remove_Elements" select="/Remove_Elements_List"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="$Remove_Elements" />
    <xsl:template match="Remove_Elements_List" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the xml is like

```
<web:Body xmlns:web="http://webservices.com" xmlns:bean="http://beans.com">

    <Remove_Elements_List>isInJeopardy</Remove_Elements_List>

      <web:terminateSubscriber>
         <web:terminateSubscriberRequest>
            <bean:accountNo>4638020</bean:accountNo>
            <bean:acctExternalId>46380206</bean:acctExternalId>
            <bean:actionCode>1</bean:actionCode>
            <bean:annotation1></bean:annotation1>
            <bean:annotation2></bean:annotation2>
            <bean:annotation3></bean:annotation3>
            <bean:changeWho>MyDomain</bean:changeWho>
            <bean:disconnectReason>3</bean:disconnectReason>
            <bean:emfConfigId>341</bean:emfConfigId>
            <bean:equipStatus>1</bean:equipStatus>
            <bean:externalId>venkat.com</bean:externalId>
            <bean:itemDate>14-Oct-2014</bean:itemDate>
            <bean:levelCode>2</bean:levelCode>
            <bean:memberType>3</bean:memberType>
            <bean:orderData>
               <bean:auditTrail></bean:auditTrail>
               <bean:changeWho></bean:changeWho>
               <bean:departmentId></bean:departmentId>
               <bean:elementId></bean:elementId>
               <bean:fileId></bean:fileId>
               <bean:isInJeopardy></bean:isInJeopardy>
               <bean:orderId></bean:orderId>
               <bean:orderIdResets></bean:orderIdResets>
               <bean:orderRevNo></bean:orderRevNo>
               <bean:orderStatus></bean:orderStatus>
               <bean:orderUrgency></bean:orderUrgency>
               <bean:owner></bean:owner>
               <bean:parentMemberType></bean:parentMemberType>
               <bean:provGroupId></bean:provGroupId>
               <bean:serverId></bean:serverId>
               <bean:subscrNo></bean:subscrNo>
               <bean:subscrNoResets></bean:subscrNoResets>
               <bean:supervisorId></bean:supervisorId>
               <bean:technicianId></bean:technicianId>
               <bean:trackingId></bean:trackingId>
               <bean:trackingIdServ></bean:trackingIdServ>
            </bean:orderData>
            <bean:subscrNo>205135041</bean:subscrNo>
            <bean:subscrNoResets>0</bean:subscrNoResets>
         </web:terminateSubscriberRequest>
      </web:terminateSubscriber>
   </web:Body>
```

Im new to XSLT and cant figure out whats wrong, can anyone please help.

Comment: Why isn't there any element named `isInJeopardy` in your input example?

Comment: bean:isInJeopardy it has a namespace but I will be getting only tag names. based on them I should remove all occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems with your approach:

1. you cannot use a variable in a match pattern;
2. the match pattern must contain an *XPath expression*; you are passing it a *string*;
3. Remove_Elements_List is not the root element, so the expression `/Remove_Elements_List` selects nothing.

Try replacing this:

```
<xsl:template match="$Remove_Elements" />
```

with:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()=//Remove_Elements_List]"/>
```

Note that this assumes that:

1. the `Remove_Elements_List` element contains one element name - not a *list* as one might think;
2. the `Remove_Elements_List` element is not in a namespace.

---

### Edit:

> In some cases I will be receiving multiple elements delimited by a
>   pipe like
>   `<Remove_Elements_List>isInJeopardy|orderId</Remove_Elements_List>` how
>   can i handle this ?

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(concat('|', //Remove_Elements_List, '|'), concat('|', local-name(), '|'))]"/>
```

Note that overall this is not a good system to have. For one thing, your `<Remove_Elements_List>` lists elements with no regard for their namespace or their position in the input tree. For another, it's not very efficient.

Comment: This works fine for ne element In some cases I will be receiving multiple elements delimited by a pipe like  <Remove_Elements_List>isInJeopardy|orderId</Remove_Elements_List>
how can i handle this ?

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, I will put this point in. Hopefully they will change the approach. but if I may ask... what would be a good approach to remove xml elements based on a real-time decision?

Comment: @AashishKotagiri I am afraid I don't know enough about your particular situation to answer that. If the data provider knows that some elements need to be removed, why don't they remove them at the source? If that's not convenient, perhaps they should tag the elements, for example by adding an attribute to them, so that they can be easily selected.

Comment: Im in middleware tire This requirement rose when client decided that he wanted to control not only 
who is receiving the data but the data itself, so each requesting party will have a set of fields 
configured for which they are not authorized to access... this varies on requester to requester basis... 
Thats why this idea of deleting elements based on content came into trails... 
and I Proposed that this can be achieved in XSLT with a minimum effort... your suggestions are working great I have tested them on a couple of XMLs... since you mentioned this  is not a good approach I wanted to here